# How can I track how many days I've used a UK Flexi Season Ticket for when it's in QR code format?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, trainline

I'm looking to purchase a UK [Flexi Season Ticket](https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/tickets-railcards-and-offers/ticket-types/flexi-season-tickets/) online, specifically using [thetrainline](https://www.thetrainline.com/) (although I'm ultimately travelling with Thameslink). I would like to get it in QR code format as I believe it's more convenient than carrying around an additional Smartcard.

If I purchase one of these tickets using a
[Key Smartcard](https://www.thameslinkrailway.com/tickets/the-key-smartcard), I can track how many journeys (or more specifically, how many days) I've used so far by holding it up against my phone with the [Thameslink app](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/thameslink-on-track-uk-train/id908805038) or similar.

If I get the QR code version instead, is there any way to track how much I've used it? I've checked thetrainline's FAQs but they are not forthcoming.

Comment: I am quite sure the balance would be shown either directly on the QR or very near that code

Comment: I can confirm that national rail's app won't do this - I installed it this morning to check the flexi season on my smartcard, and it's only for NFCs.  Is it a printed QR or on your phone in a specific app?  I had so much trouble with GWR's app (e.g. unlock the app, walk up to the gateline, find it had locked again) that I went back to a physical card.  It's so much easier - for me.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella the QR code is just a code - it's a static image. For example, it's available through email, through Apple Wallet - where are you expecting that balance would be? I don't see how that mechanism would work.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK I don't have one yet, but I believe it's the same form factor as any other e-rail ticket in the UK. Hence me asking before I got it ;)

Comment: It seems fundamentally different - the smartcard has storage where it can keep data about how it's been used, but the QR code of course is little more than a database key.  So it's got to be an official app/website with access to the database.  GWR's website just about gives that, but it seems to flush the data overnight, so when it says "1 passes [sic] remaining" that might include today's that you've already activated.  Their app may do something similar, but I uninstalled it before I got my smartcard.  Trainline being involved may not be helping

Comment: Suggestion: you get a smartcard first, registering with Thameslink. Install whatever app Thameslink suggest to view your *account*, and if that works, think about going for a QR version.  Alternative suggestion: go straight to a QR, but keep manual records until you've tested Thameslink's app of choice

Comment: @ChrisH-UK yeah, I'm not sure any of these apps have the possibility of scanning the code, is the problem :( I'm going to try it through Trainline and see what happens. Worst case I have to track it myself.

Comment: If the app is logged in to the account to which the ticket is registered, you shouldn't need the QR code itself.  I can go in to my account on GWR and with a few (too many, too subtle) clicks get the information about the flexi-season I have on that account.  As I have been able to with print-at-home QR tickets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having done this now, I can answer my own question. When I buy my Flexi Season Ticket from the trainline, for example, the QR code is handled a little differently than for a regular return ticket. Each day I want to use it, I log into the Trainline app and 'activate' that day. This generates a unique QR code which is valid only for that day. This QR code cannot be transferred e.g. to Apple Wallet unlike "regular" QR codes (although I believe it's still fundamentally a QR code, just the app handles it differently).

Below the ticket in the trainline app is listed the number of days left on which the ticket can be used.

Comment: Nice result.  I stand by my earlier comment: "Trainline being involved may not be helping" but it seems less bad than GWR's app.

Comment: Well in my case, the train operator is Thameslink, and their way of buying a Flexi Season ticket seems to require one of their smartcards, so from my experience so far having tried both, the Trainline app is superior, now I've solved this problem.